# Finding array with empty elements

Tags: scala

I have the following structure:

```
val s1 = Seq(1,2,3,4,5)
val s2 = Seq()
val s3 = Seq(6,7,8,9)
val seq = Seq(s1,s2,s3)
```

What I need is to validate that all the sequences in `seq` have at least one element. I tried to accomplish this with filter, but couldn't, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `forall` function:

```
seq.forall(!_.isEmpty)
```

which translates into: `Are all sequences in seq non-empty?` and thus returns false with your example since `s2` is empty.

Comment: Or `seq.forall(_.nonEmpty)`.

Answer (score 1):

This finds all the sequences with at least one element

```
seq.filterNot(_.isEmpty)
```

while this checks that all sequences have at least one element

```
seq.forAll(!_.isEmpty)
```

or

```
!seq.exists(_.isEmpty)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below line of code.

```
val distinct=seq.filter(_.length>0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should also work.

```
seq.filter(_.nonEmpty)
```